# Why does Lenovo Vantage show other updates than pcsupport.lenovo.com?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

I usually use Lenovo Vantage and Windows Update to keep my windows 10 and all the drivers up to date on my Lenovo Thinkpad.

Now I found out that when I enter my serial number at pcsupport.lenovo.com, some updates are shown, that Lenovo Vantage never showed to me? Why? Does Lenovo Vantage somehow know more details about the current state of my system and deliberatle not recommends them to me (maybe because they were not enough tested with my configuration)? Or is Lenovo Vantage too stupid to check the correct Lenovo server?

What would happen if I install Lenovo Service Bridge to run an automatic update scan from pcsupport.lenovo.com from the browser? Does it internally do the same as Lenovo Vantage or has Lenovo implemented 2 tools for basically the same purpose with different strenghts and weaknesses? What are the different pros and cona of these tools when or by whom should they be used.

(I just want a system that runs stable, I don't need the latest stuff. Right now it doesn't run stable so I am searching for updates, but I only want updates that are properly tested and checked for compatibility with my configuration. I guess when I use windows harware manager to update specific drivers, there was less checking and testing done than when I use drivers recommended by Lenovo?)

Comment: Lenovo System Updates will normally show the same updates as the manual list. There may be a 2-week difference either way as the manual list is not always 100% the same as Lenovo Updater

Comment: There are multiple Intel Thunderbolt updates from May 27/28 that are shown on pcsupport.lenovo.com but not at Lenovo Vantage. Is this a sagin that something is wrong with my Intel Thunderbolt installation?

Comment: Lenovo will provide you with the correct drivers for your machine. You should use other (third party) update with great caution. Windows updates are normally fine (but Lenovo has provided the update in the majority of machine types.

Comment: On pcsupport.lenovo.com Lenovotells me that these drivers are recommended,but Vantage doesn't show them to me. This is why I am confused.

Comment: That is because it takes time for the systems to sync. I the Lenovo Support page for your specific model has an update, you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo Support may show drivers that may not apply to your exact computer model,
so installing them will just take a bit of disk space, but for nothing.

Lenovo Vantage will examine your hardware and suggest updates that really pertain.
It is of courseincomplete without Windows Update.
In fact, Windows Update may sometimes offer newer versions than Lenovo Vantage.

Note that keeping zealously your computer always up-to-date may sometimes be
problematic, if the new software was not tested enough. I myself prefer to
postpone updates as much as possible, to give the manufacturer time enough to
correct the new bugs.